# How to manually set a property in Sonata Admin ListMapper from database

Tags: symfony, doctrine, sonata-admin

My model has a "parent" entity called Application and a "child" entity called "role" which joins to application via a ManyToOne relationship.

However, Application does not have an inverse "oneToMany" relationship to Role for performance reasons.

What I'm trying to do is to join a role entity to the application entity on the Application's Sonata Admin List.

The closest I've been able to come is using createQuery on the applicationAdmin class like so:

```
public function createQuery($context = 'list'){
    $query = parent::createQuery($context);
    $query
        ->leftJoin('fnBundle:Role','r','WITH','r.application = ' . $query->getRootAlias() . '.id')
        ->leftJoin('fnBundle:User','u','WITH','ar.user = u')
        ->addSelect('u.email');
    return $query;
}
```

This dies with the following error:

> "Warning: get_class() expects parameter 1 to be object, array given")
>   in "SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_list_field.html.twig"

I believe (though I've had trouble proving) this is because the return application object is nested in an array with two keys like

```
array(0 => <Application Object>, 1 => <User Email>);
```

instead of just the application object.

So how would I go about fixing this? Can I select the u.email AS a property of the application (I don't think so, I've been looking for a solution)...should I override the DataGrid somehow, or is there no elegant solution to this problem?

Thanks!